# Function called from custom hook in React Native returns is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am getting a error with my code in React Native.
I am trying to make a custom hook which retrieves the display name from Firebase but currently React Native is saying "_readDb.useDisplayName is not a function"

**Custom hook (readDb)**

```
import { db } from "../model/config"; // import the db config
import { get, ref, set, child } from "firebase/database";
import useAuth from "./useAuth";
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

function useDisplayName() {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const userId = user.uid;

  useEffect(() => {
    get(child(ref(db), "users/" + userId)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        setDisplayName(snapshot.val().username);
      } else {
        console.log("No data available");
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return displayName;
}

export default useDisplayName;
```

**HomeScreen**

```
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { writeUserName } from "../../hooks/useWriteDb";
import { useDisplayName } from "../../hooks/readDb";

export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  const { signOut, user } = useAuth();
  const name = useDisplayName();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Turns out I got it fixed from changing export default useDisplayName; to export {useDisplayName} why is that?

Comment: Because `import { useDisplayName }` is looking for a named export, not the default export.

Answer (score 1):

You're destructuring the import:

`import { useDisplayName } from "../../hooks/readDb";`

So you have to export as an object:

`export { useDisplayName };`

Or, export as written in the question, and import without destructuring:

`import useDisplayName from "../../hooks/readDb";`